# Cloud9 error when running project "Error retrieving pid file"

Tags: pid, cloud9-ide

I have been playing around with the Cloud9 web-based IDE learning PHP 
Today I went to run my project, and was presented with this error:

```
(20014)Internal error: AH00058: Error retrieving pid file /home/ubuntu/lib/apache2/run/apache2.pid                                                                                                                                     
AH00059: Remove it before continuing if it is corrupted.
```

I have since been able to migrate my work using XAMPP, but would like to resolve my Cloud9 issue.  Does anyone know how to resolve this in the Cloud9 environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got Same type problem & solution as follows. Hope someone may helpfull

> Problem:
>
> Started apache2
>   (20014)Internal error: AH00058: Error retrieving pid file
>   /home/ubuntu/lib/apache2/run/apache2.pid
>   AH00059: Remove it before continuing if it is corrupted.

Solution:

```
sudo rm /home/ubuntu/lib/apache2/run/apache2.pid  then
sudo /home/ubuntu/lib/apache2/run/apache2.pid restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I feel rather dumb...resolved the issue myself by using Cloud9's terminal to navigate to the directory and then removed the corrupt file.

Comment: Which file deleted?